# how to pass multiple csv files as input to NEWMAN

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

How to pass multiple csv files in newman run?

newman run CollectionRunner.json --global-var IP_PORT="http://127.0.0.1:8088/" -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-title "Result Report"  --reporter-htmlextra-export /home/reports/HARISH.html  --iteration-data /home/dataset1.csv

I want to pass multiple data sets to the collection, I have dataset1,dataset2,dataset3,dataset4 in my directory. all should gets executed for the collectionRunner and the RESULT REPORT should contain all the result,

I tried something like this,
newman run CollectionRunner.json --global-var IP_PORT="http://127.0.0.1:8088/" -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-title "Result Report"  --reporter-htmlextra-export /home/reports/Result.html  --iteration-data /home/dataset1.csv --iteration-data /home/dataset2.csv --iteration-data /home/dataset3.csv

But its not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Unix system, maybe you can try this before running Newman:

paste -d, dataset1.csv dataset2.csv > merged-dataset.csv